# How to maintain the precedence of an object inside a priority queue once it is being taken out to update its priority?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am wondering if there is anyway to maintain the precedence of an object inside a priority queue once it is being removed and reinserted into the queue to update its priority?

The way I do this is that I remove the object from the priority queue and put the updated object into the queue again. However, this will disrupt the natural ordering I had implemented using `Comparator`

The `Comparator`:

```
class PriorityValueComparator implements Comparator<Human>{
    public int compare(Human x, Human y){
        return y._priority - x._priority;
    }
}
```

For example,

> insert in the following order: John, Alex, Kerby, Jane
>
> The priority queue is in the following form: [Jane, 100], [Kerby, 59], [Alex, 33], [John, 13]
>
> Update John to 100
>
> [John, 100] **(since John is inserted before Jane)**,  [Jane, 100], [Kerby, 59], [Alex, 33]

**UPDATE:**
Alternatively, in the *Human* Class, a static attribute `time` can be added. Inside the constructor of *Human*,

```
public Human() {
    //add in whatever you want here
    time++; //This will ensure that every elements will have their own unique order number
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. If you're updating its priority, why do you want to leave it at its old priority?

Comment: Because he is actually the first one to enter this priority queue and I would like to maintain that order when it is updated. I am just wondering if this can be done.

Comment: So you want insertion order on top of the heap behavior?

Comment: @jials Your question doesn't make sense. The priority is determined by the comparator. If you change it, you change it. There aren't two priorities. If you want to make insertion order part of the comparison, use it as a minor key in your comparator, if you can find a way to maintain it.

Comment: @Delimanolis Yep. That's the thing I'm trying to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority queue implementation is allowed to choose arbitrarily between elements with the same priority. If you want to force a particular order, then you need to change the comparator. Assuming that you maintain a field `_insertion_time` such that humans inserted earlier have lesser, nonnegative values, then you can rewrite the comparator to

```
class PriorityValueComparator implements Comparator<Human>{
    public int compare(Human x, Human y){
        if (y._priority != x._priority) return y._priority - x._priority;
        else return y._insertion_time - x._insertion_time;
    }
}
```